# App Crashes upon receiving data from intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two activities that I would like to send data between. I would like to send two strings from the second activity to the first, where the strings will be manipulated and applied to the code. Here is the intent I have in the second activity to send the strings to the first activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    phoneNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNum);
    msgCounter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msgCount);
    apply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butto);
    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butt);


    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent pass = new Intent();
            pass.putExtra("value", phoneNum.getText().toString());
            pass.putExtra("cost",msgCounter.getText().toString());
            startActivity(pass);
        }
    });
```

And here is the intent I have in the first acitivity to receive the data:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_messages);
    request_code = 1;

    FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.but);

    assert button != null;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(TextMessages.this,Settings.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, request_code);

            Intent a = new Intent(TextMessages.this,Settings.class);
            startActivityForResult(a, recode);

        }
    });


    Intent pass = getIntent();
    String address = pass.getStringExtra("value");
    String string2 = pass.getStringExtra("cost");
```

However, the app always crashes when I start it. So I can not use any of the data. Thanks in advance to any help I may receive.

Comment: In your first code, you don't have a Context or an Activity in your Intent.

Comment: Please post error log?

Comment: It is clear that you don't have a context `Intent pass = new Intent("context", someActivity.class);`. Please post the error log to help you with better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first activity you should get your strings from onActivityResult. You shouldn't use startActivity in second activity.

Checkout this link for more information
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

In your second activity you should use setResult method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

phoneNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNum);
msgCounter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msgCount);
apply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butto);
save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butt);


save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent pass = new Intent();
        pass.putExtra("value", phoneNum.getText().toString());
        pass.putExtra("cost",msgCounter.getText().toString());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,pass);
        finish();
    }
});
```

In your first activity you should get Intent data inside the onActivityResult method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == request_code) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String value=data.getStringExtra("value");
            String cost=data.getStringExtra("cost");
            //handle value and cost.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you missed out to put the target Activity class when you instantiate your intent. It should be like this:

```
Intent pass = new Intent(TargetActivity.class);
pass.putExtra("value", phoneNum.getText().toString());
pass.putExtra("cost",msgCounter.getText().toString());
startActivity(pass);
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT: But I agree with Abdullah. Since the first activity started the second activity, use onActivityResult to pass values to the first activity.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, the app starts into the second code block you posted. There is no value for `String address = pass.getStringExtra("value");` or `String string2 = pass.getStringExtra("cost");` when you start your app - only when the second activity sends these to the first activity. I would recommend finding a way to determine if its the second activity creating the first activity or creating a method to set these values in the first activity and call it in the second activity. Also, your second activity should be:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    phoneNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNum);
    msgCounter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msgCount);
    apply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butto);
    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butt);


    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent pass = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
            pass.putExtra("value", phoneNum.getText().toString());
            pass.putExtra("cost",msgCounter.getText().toString());
            startActivity(pass);
        }
    });
```